# Removing the last comma

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to remove the last comma from my print method. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you.

```
    public void print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(M[i][j] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Output:

1.5,2.0,3.0,

3.0,2.5,4.0,

2.5,4.0,2.5,

I ended up adding an "if" statement to solve the same problem.
Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
    public void print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
            if(j == M[i].length-1){
                System.out.print(M[i][j] +" ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(M[i][j] + ",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Output:

1.5,2.0,3.0

3.0,2.5,4.0

2.5,4.0,2.5

Comment: System.out.print( ((j == 0) ? "" : ",") + M[i][j]);

Answer (score 3):

I often use this idiom for this problem -- make a variable `comma` special (`""`) for the first time, and then restore it to the normal state (`", "`) for the second time and onward:

```
public void print() {
    for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
        String comma = "";      // first time special
        for(int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(comma + M[i][j]);
            comma = ",";        // second time onward
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use an `if else` statement in your second `for` loop.
And instead of putting the comma at the back, it's better to put it at the front.
The sample code looks like this:

```
public void print(){
    int[][] M = {{1,3},{2,3,4},{5,6},{5,2}};
    for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
            if (j==0)
                System.out.print(M[i][j]);
            else
                System.out.print(","+M[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The code will output

> 1,3
>
> 2,3,4
>
> 5,6
>
> 5,2

Answer (score 1):

In your second for loop, add an if statement that checks to see if it's the last item of the list. If it is, omit the comma. Else, put the comma.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Your comment helped and I have edited my question adding  the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public void print() {
for(int i = 0; i < M.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < M[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(M[i][j]);
       if (i < M.length-1 || j < M[i].length - 1) {
          System.out.print(",")
       }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Basically it checks if the element is the last in the array and if not, it prints the comma. if it is it doesn't print the comma. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `","` before the item instead of after, and simply don't print it before the first item:

```java
public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
        if (M[i].length != 0) {
            System.out.print(M[i][0]);
        }
        for(int j = 1; j < M[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("," + M[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You might also want to store the row in a variable so that you don't keep accessing the `i`th element of `M` repeatedly:

```java
public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
        final type[] row = M[i];
        if (row.length != 0) {
            System.out.print(row[0]);
        }
        for(int j = 1; j < row.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("," + row[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool Java 8 way of doing it if you like streams. Works with arrays of int/double :D

```
Arrays.stream(M)
      .map(x -> Arrays.stream(x)
                  .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```